# When I pipe the service --status-all command to grep, why do extra lines show up in the output?

Tags: shell

For example,

```
sudo service --status-all | grep -oE 'php[0-9]+.[0-9]+'
```

generates the following output.

```
 [ ? ]  hwclock.sh
 [ ? ]  networking
php7.0
php7.3
```

My goal is to extract the version of another software package and put it into a configuration script so that the script won't break if that package gets upgraded or downgraded.  If my understanding of regular expressions and the piping operator is correct, the *first two lines shouldn't even show up in the output*.

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Make sure that those lines aren't coming from stderr? `sudo service --status-all 2>/dev/null | grep -oE 'php[0-9]+.[0-9]+'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirecting the output to stderr eliminated the unwanted lines.  I also piped the output to **tail -1** to get the last line only--the one with the latest version.

```
sudo service --status-all 2>/dev/null | grep -oE 'php[0-9]+.[0-9]+' | tail -1
```